# Simple generators with a complex Gröbner basis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra-systems

It's known that finding a Gröbner basis of a polynomial ideal has a worst-case space complexity of [$O(2^{2^{c\cdot n}})$](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Buchberger%27s_algorithm#Complexity), where c is constant and n is the number of variables $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

However, in practice it seems that most ideals have a simple Gröbner basis.

Can anyone give some concrete examples of small generators whose ideal has a large Gröbner basis?
How would I go about searching for such examples (besides a brute-force approach of trying random ideals)?

Comment: Point of interest: As far as I've heard, the bad examples people used to show the worst-case complexity are not very geometrical in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the following example, from [this paper](https://www.math.lsu.edu/system/files/Groeb_Project_revised_final.pdf):

GroebnerBasis[{x^5 + y^5 + z^5 - 1, x^3 + y^3 + z^2 - 1}, {x, y, z}] (* Is long *)

Answer (score -1):

$$ (x5+y5+z5−1x3+y3+z2−1)(xyz)
=(x5+y5+z5+−x3+y3+z2+−1)(xyz)
=(x5)(xyz)+(y5)(xyz)+(z5)(xyz)+(−x3)(xyz)+(y3)(xyz)+(z2)(xyz)+(−1)(xyz)
=x6yz+xy6z+xyz6−x4yz+xy4z+xyz3−xyz
=x6yz+xy6z+xyz6−x4yz+xy4z+xyz3−xyz $$

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). You can [edit] your post to improve its appearance.