# Do Groebner bases give the smallest generating set for Ideals?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Given a Reduced Groebner Basis $(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ for an ideal $I$, can there be another basis $(g_1,\ldots,g_m)$ for $I$ where $m<n$?

I've been reading through Cox, but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Is the ideal $(x z - y^2, x^2 y - z^2, x^3 - y z)$ a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Zhen has suggested a counterexample and there is another [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254105/simple-generators-with-a-complex-grobner-basis).  In practice some ideals have grobner bases that are so large we do not know what they are because the computer calculation takes too long and requires to much memory to actually complete.  As far as finding a minimal generating set of an ideal choosing a grobner basis, even a reduced one, is a very bad strategy.

See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34544/size-of-a-groebner-basis) math overflow post.

Comment: Where can I learn more about finding minimal generating set? Is there some notion of dimension analogous to linear algebra?

Comment: There are various notions of the dimension of a ring, some of which have to do with minimal generating sets of primary ideals.  I would check Eisenbud and see what's in there.